# Алгоритм замены данных в базе данных

Tags: php

Есть данные, которые я беру от API. Иногда этот API любит подлагивать и возвращает данные с задержкой в 5-6, а иногда и 20-30 секунд, что, разумеется, критично и пользователь может просто не дождавшись получения интересующей его информации уйти с сайта. Принял решение класть полученные от API данные в БД и вытаскивать их по следующему алгоритму:

1. Пользователь зашёл на сайт. Автоматически при загрузке страницы ушёл запрос на получение данных к PHP посредством AJAX-запроса.
2. PHP получил данные для запроса и инициировал обращение к внешнему серверу.
3. Данные от API получены. Сверяем MD5-хэши имеющихся и полученных данных. Если хэши совпадают - отдаём из базы, если нет - кладём новопришедшие данные в БД с заменой.

Но я не учёл того, что пока сервер будет ждать ответа от API, то он не сможет сравнить хэши и, соответственно, отдать пользователю данные из базы. Я придумал, как это можно решить: просто отдаём сразу данные из БД, а потом уже в фоне ждём ответа от API и сверяем актуальность данных. Если данные неактуальны - кладём в БД и при последующих запросах уже будут выводиться свежие данные. В связи с этим, у меня вопрос: я ведь могу достать данные из базы, сделать `return $data;` в функции предварительно вызвав другую функцию, которая будет в фоне ждать ответа на запрос и проверять данные? Будет ли это работать? Возможно, я слишком сложно всё придумал и есть варианты попроще?

Comment: А зачем запрашивать данные у API всегда после того как они пользователю понадобились. может хоть какие нибудь таймауты ввести, что бы не перезапрашивать данные, которые возможно редко меняются. А общение с api вообще лучше вынести из php, запускающихся web-сервером, а повесить в крон или постоянно запущенным фоновым процессом на сервере, не зависимо от web

Comment: @Mike мне нравится с PHP работать отправляя через него запросы и тут лично мне менять что-то не очень хочется. С таймаутами, пожалуй, соглашусь. Это хорошее замечание.

Comment: но вы так и будете отправлять запросы из php-кода. весь вопрос лишь в том, каким образом этот php-код запущен. клиенты обращаются к web-серверу, web-сервер запускает php код, при этом все время пока php код не завершился данный процесс web-сервера занят и не может обслуживать других клиентов. но ведь есть масса способов запустить php-код вообще не имея web-сервера ... и тогда этот самый код не будет занимать такого ценного ресурса как процесс web-сервера

Comment: В старинных версиях PHP можно было отдать клиенту страницу, потом закрыть stdout и еще что-то сделать, требующее времени. Возможно, это и сейчас работает.

Comment: @Mike в любом случае, я могу установить таймаут, в течение которого PHP будешь только доставать данные из БД и не будет делать лишние запросы ко внешнему серверу. И Вы мне так и не ответили, будет ли работать функция в фоне после того, как я после её вызова сделаю return :)

Comment: Я не понимаю как у вас функция будет чего то ждать в фоне и как вы сделаете return после того, как вызовете функцию. обычно когда вы чего то вызываете, тот кто вызвал ждет результата и следовательно сам сделать return не может. Если же это что то асинхронное, то надо понимать как именно отправляется запрос к API. может самое это API асинхронное и вы ему послали запрос и можете отключиться, а потом подключиться опять и забрать результат